# QgsRelationEditorWidget in Custom form

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-custom-widgets

I have made a custom form with a **QgsRelationEditorWidget** and with a **QToolButton**. I want to select a feature in this **QgsRelationEditorWidget** and press the button to open another form with this selected feature. For it, I need to get this selected feature attributes. The code is a py file.

I think I have to access to the **QgsRelationEditorWidget** with this code:

```
childFormWidget = dialog.findChildren(QgsRelationEditorWidget)[0]
childForm = childFormWidget.findChildren(QgsRelationEditorWidget)[0]
featureManager = childForm.featureSelectionManager()
infraManager.selectionChanged.connect(partial(changeSelection, featureManager))
```

But I have this error:

> IndexError: list index out of range.

Also, I don't know how to access the attributes with featureManager.

How can I do it? How can I reach to the selected feature?

Answer (score 2):

In case someone needs it, finally I understood how does QgsIFeatureSelectionManager work.
This code takes the selected features ids from a QgsRelationEditorWidget and passes it to the function "changeSelection" when we change the selection in widget.

```
childFormWidget = dialog.findChildren(QgsRelationEditorWidget)[0]
featureManager = childFormWidget.featureSelectionManager()
featureManager.selectionChanged.connect(changeSelection)
```

Then we define the changeSelection function. Here we access to the selected features by:

```
def changeSelection(deselected, selected):
    feat=selected               
    idact= feat[0]
```

Now with the feature's id, we can do all we need. In this case, I only select one feature en QgsRelationEditorWidget (feat[0])

Answer (score 0):

After changing the code as follow:

```
childFormWidget = dialog.findChildren(QgsRelationEditorWidget)[0]
featureManager = childFormWidget.featureSelectionManager()
feat=featureManager.selectedFeatureCount ()
```

I get the correct value of feat, in this case, 1. But I still can not get the attributes of the selected feature.